# Refering multiple beans using annotation configuration

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-annotations, spring-bean

When using spring with xml configuration we can refer or add dependencies of multiple beans to one bean by writing the same similar code

```
<beans>
   <bean id ="parent" class="com.Parent">
   <property name = "child1" ref = "child1"/>
   <property name = "child2" ref = "child2"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id = "child1" class="com.child">
   <property name = "name" value = "abc"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id = "child2" class="com.child">
   <property name = "name" value = "xyz"/>
   </bean>
</beans>
```

Now I have below code I want to refer 2 cars beans per home bean
I'm using qualifier to tackle ambiguity, could we refer multiple beans using qualifier or something else??

```
Configfile.java

        @Bean("jeep")
    public Car returnJeep()
    {
        Car c = new Car();
        c.setName("Wrangler");
        return c;
    }

    @Bean("volvo")
    public Car returnVolvo()
    {
        Car c = new Car();
        c.setName("Volvo");

        return c;
    }

Home.java

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("volvo,jeep") --> How can I refer multiple beans here????
    private Car car;

    @Override
    public void print() {
        System.out.println("Cheers!!, now you own a new home and a "+ car.getName());
    }
```

One way to achieve this is to create one more reference of class car and using qualifier specifying the other bean name which works, is there any other way to achieve this?

Could we to achieve the same by using @Components i.e one bean referring to multiple beans?

Comment: i think what you need is `decorator pattern`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to add multiple bean qualifiers to the same property. However, you can have multiple properties of the same type. Something like this:

```java
@Component
public class Home {

    private final Car Volvo;
    private final Car jeep;

    public Home(@Qualifier("volvo") Car volvo, @Qualifier("jeep") Car jeep) {
        this.volvo = volvo;
        this.jeep = jeep;
    }

    // your code goes here

}
```

Another way to achieve the same is by using a `Map`, like this:

```java
@Component
public class Home {

    private final Map<String, Car> carMap;
    private final Car jeep;

    public Home(Map<String, Car> carMap) {
        this.carMap = carMap;
    }

    // your code goes here

}
```

Using the map approach the `key` will be the `qualifier` name and the value will be the implementation for that qualifier.

[A working sample can be found on this GitHub repo](https://github.com/marcosbarbero/spring-inject-multiple-beans-same-type)

Comment: The above mentioned approach doesn't work, results in to exceptions, anyways I will try some other workaround, your approach did manage to kick my brain to think more in depth. Thanks

Comment: Which exception?

Comment: No qualifying bean of type 'com.SpringTrial.Car' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=volvo)}

Comment: I'm sorry but that has nothing to do with I showed you, you simply didn't declare the bean, you won't be able to inject something that's not declared.

Comment: I have declared the bean Car as @Component, and in the Home.java I'm declaring them as a private final field as showed above, I'm I missing something else because it works when I'm creating one reference of a Car without using qualifier.

Comment: I've added a working sample to the bottom, you can check it out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211142/discussion-between-shelly-and-marcos-barbero).

Comment: I saw that example you are using annotation Beans, I was thinking for a way to achieve the same using Components